# ¿Cómo pasó "estraperlo" de designar una ruleta fraudulenta a su significado actual de "mercado negro"?

Tags: historia, españa

En Wikipedia se recoge en el artículo [**estraperlo**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estraperlo) que:

> El término **estraperlo** o **straperlo** es usado en España para referirse al comercio ilegal de bienes sometidos a algún tipo de impuesto o tasa por el Estado. Por extensión, es una actividad irregular o intriga de algún tipo, y se usa como sinónimo de mercado negro.

Sin embargo, el significado original, recogido en el [**DLE**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GxH7EX5) es:

> De *Straperlo*, nombre de una especie de ruleta fraudulenta que se intentó implantar en España en 1935, y este acrón. de D. *Strauss* y J. *Perlowitz*, sus creadores.

¿Cómo pasó el nombre de una ruleta fraudulenta a significar mercado negro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En [el blog de Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/el-origen-de-la-palabra-estraperlo/) se nos cuenta lo siguiente, que de momento viene a corroborar lo que comentas en la pregunta:

> La palabra Estraperlo proviene de Straperlo y ésta deriva como acrónimo de Strauss y Perlowitz (en algunas fuentes aparece tan solo como Perlo), dos socios de origen holandés que en época de la Segunda República trajeron a España una ruleta eléctrica. Dicha ruleta se presentó en sociedad en 1934 en el Casino de San Sebastián y también llegó a llevarse a Palma de Mallorca.
>
> Por lo visto habían sobornado a varios políticos influyentes y así consiguieron introducirla en el país. Evidentemente, la ruleta estaba trucada y rápidamente las autoridades se dieron cuenta del timo y se prohibió dicho juego.

En la hemeroteca de la BNE se encuentran artículos que hablan del caso desde 1936, haciendo referencia al caso como "lo del estraperlo". La forma en que se introdujo la máquina en el país, de forma fraudulenta y de tapadillo, debió dar origen al uso del término para cualquier actividad del mismo corte. Curiosamente, es un académico de la RAE, Julián Marías, quien en su [discurso de ingreso](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Discurso_ingreso_Julian_Marias.pdf) nos habla de la palabra. Está comentando la situación actual del diccionario y cómo las palabras contienen definiciones, como la primera de "planeta" por aquel entonces, que están ahí porque alguna vez fueron *uso*, pero no se corresponden con el habla actual. Y entonces compara la situación de las definiciones "históricas" con aquellas palabras que recién se están formando:

> Compárese esta situación con la de la palabra 'estraperlo', a cuyo origen y uso hemos asistido. Derivada de dos nombres propios, Strauss y Perle, hacia 1934 viene a designar un negocio de probidad dudosa, y se convierte en sinónimo del francés *affaire*; pero muy pronto, ya durante la guerra civil y en los años que la siguen, época de escasez general, la palabra 'estraperlo' sufre un cambio semántico y se hace equivalente de 'mercado ilegal' o 'mercado negro'. La forma en que esta voz se usa es muy peculiar: 'de estraperlo': comprar o vender 'de estraperlo', productos 'de estraperlo'.